# How do I specify where a GET protocol could get resource from?

Tags: javascript, express

So if I GET "/home" and say I would server home.html. I would like to specify where to get all the resources I include in home.html file from. So if I have a file system like this

```
-public
    -home.html
    -home
    -src
```

and I keep all the resource home.html use inside src. Then when I GET /home I don't want the route to go into home folder and try to serve file in there which will result to a 404. If I source a js file inside src in home.html and I serve home.html when I GET /home, I would like the route to stay in public then go to src/file.js and serve it not /home/src/file.js. If that is not possible could someone tell me how to structure the files better so that I could easily serve file as I want.

Answer (score 0):

If in home.html you have

```
<script src="src/file.js"></script>
```

when express serves the home.html page, it will look for public/src/file.js if the public folder has been setup to serve static files in your express app.

You can do this by adding the following to your app.js:

```
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

That is assuming your dir structure is:

```
-root
    -public
        -home.html
        -home
        -src
    app.js
```

Comment: I have just the same thing, but when I source file.js inside home.html like that it tried to look for it in localhost/home/src/file.js instead of localhost/src/file.js, Which is how it work before I created the home folder inside public.

Comment: Can you make a gist of your project? Would be easier to help if I could see your code.